# calling async with a delegate to pass the method call into a method

Tags: c#, delegates

I have the following code and I'm trying to write a delegate that allows the service call to be passed into the method but I'm really struggling.
Can anyone suggest how this is possible?

Many thanks,

This is a simple example, but notice how the two methods are the same, except for the internal service call they each make.  I want to pass the method they call into a DoIt method, i.e.

**Example**

```
var result1 = DoIt(await _service.GetMethodA(..))

var result2 = DoIt(await _service.GetMethodB(..))
```

**Code to change**

```
async Task<ICustomer> ICustomerSomething.GetIt(Guid pupilId)
{
    var t = await _service.GetMethodA(..)
}

async Task<ICustomer> ICustomerSomething.GetSomethingElse(Guid pupilId)
{
    var t = await _service.GetMethodB(..)
}
```

**Signatures**

```
async Task<ICustomer> ICustomerService.Get(Guid pupilId)

async Task<IEnumerable<ICar>> ICustomerService.GetSomethingElse(Guid pupilId)
```

**Update**

I have made the suggested changes although it doesn't compile, shown below

**Error message**

'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'  MyService

**Code after change**

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoIt(Func<Task<IHttpActionResult>> func)
{
    return await func();
}

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(...)
{
        DoIt(() => _myService.CallinternalService(...));
}
```

Comment: Can you post the signature of methods `GetMethodA` and  `GetMethodB`? At least the `parameters` and `return type`

Answer (score 1):

[As I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html), asynchronous methods are just like synchronous methods except they return `Task`/`Task<T>` instead of `void`/`T`. So, delegates for asynchronous methods are `Func`s that return `Task`/`Task<T>`.

In this case:

```
Func<.., Task<TResult>>
```

where `TResult` is the type of `result1` and `result2`, and `..` are the types of the parameters passed to `GetMethodA` and `GetMethodB`.

This can be used as:

```
public async Task<TResult> DoIt(Func<.., Task<TResult>> func, ..)
{
  return await func(..);
}

DoIt(_service.GetMethodA, ..);
```

Alternatively, you can pass the arguments `..` in the lambda expression, which simplifies your delegate type to just `Func<Task<TResult>>`, as such:

```
public async Task<TResult> DoIt(Func<Task<TResult>> func)
{
  return await func();
}

DoIt(() => _service.GetMethodA(..));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> DoIt<T>(Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>> func)
{
    return func();
}

async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main()
{
    await DoIt(() => System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(1));

    await DoIt(() => System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(""));
}
```